# Putting Icon Shortcut on a Mobile Phone

Tags: smartphone

I have a mobile website that my customers can navigate to through the web.  I would like to be able to add an icon shortcut to their phone so that once they click on it they will go directly to the website.  I was wondering if there is a way to make this easier?  For example, when they visit the mobile website for the first time they click on a button and the script behind this button will automatically download my icon, put it on their smartphone, and link this icon to my mobile website.  Can someone advise me on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I was just googling this same issue and I found this site... http://socialmedia.biz/2012/02/21/encourage-visitors-to-save-your-site-as-a-mobile-shortcut/

Not sure if it's exactly what you are after, but it sounds about right.

Answer (score 0):

Iphone

1. Step 1: Make sure Safari is active.  Do this in settings.
2. Step 2: Open Safari and key in-your desired web page
3. Step 3: Once the site displays on the screen, there is a selection in the very middle at the bottom.  Hit it and a screen will come up showing various icons.
4. Step 4: Find the one with a plus sign at the bottom that says *add to screen*  Select it
5. Step 5: You will see that now you can just tap that new shortcut to get to the web page.